# System of Differentiation Equation : 3 variables case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let there exists $100(L)$ containers $A, B, C$ with alcohols in $A$ is $x(0) = 30$, in $B$ is $y(0) = 20$, in $C$ is $z(10) = 10$ and let $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ be an amount of alcohols in each container.

Then there exists following relations between $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ such as,

$$x' = 0.1z - 0.1x$$
$$y' = 0.1x - 0.1y$$
$$z' = 01.y - 0.1z$$

Then find $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ when $t = \infty$

---

My solution is since total amount is 60, its distribution would be equally at the end, such as 20, 20, 20 to x,y,z.

However, I also want to approach this problem to solve via eliminating other variables but leaving only $x'', x', x$ in one equation.

Any know-how to do this?

Comment: I suppose you mean $z'=\color{red}{0.1y}-0.1z$, right?

Comment: @Daschin: Also, I think you mean $z(0) = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

Note: there appear to be two typos in your problem statement, one in the three equations  ($z'$) and one in the initial conditions ($z(0)$). I used what I believe are the correct equations and ICs below.

From the first equation, we have

$$\tag 1 z = 10 x' + x \implies z' = 10 x'' + x'$$

From the second equation, we have

$$\tag 2 x = 10 y' + y \implies x' = 10y'' + y' \implies x'' = 10 y''' + y''$$

Substituting $(1)$ into the third equation, we have

$$\tag 3 10 x'' + x' = \dfrac{1}{10} y -\dfrac{1}{10} (10x' + x)$$

Now, just substitute $x, x', x''$ from $(2)$ into $(3)$ and you get a third order DEQ equation for $y(t)$ and you have all the ICs.

Solve for $y(t)$ and then use that to solve for $x(t)$ from your second equation and then the same for $z(t)$ using the first equation.

You should get (these each have a limit of $20$ as $t$ approaches $\infty$)

> $$\begin{align} x(t) &= \frac{10}{3} e^{-\frac{3 t}{20}} \left(6 e^{\frac{3 t}{20}}-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{20}\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{20}\right)\right) \\ y(t)&= \frac{20}{3} e^{-\frac{3 t}{20}} \left(3 e^{\frac{3 t}{20}}+\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{20}\right)\right) \\z(t) &= \frac{10}{3} e^{-\frac{3 t}{20}} \left(6 e^{\frac{3 t}{20}}-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{20}\right)-3 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{20}\right)\right) \end{align}$$

There are many other ways to approach these problems like eigenvalues/eigenvectors, matrix exponential, Laplace Transforms...

I will assume you can take it from here.